# php soapclient Cannot process the message because the content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not the expected type application/soap+msbin1. (HTTP)

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am attempting to connect to a WSDL generated by a Microsoft service using PHP's soapclient.  I can connect just fine, and even get the types back.  But the response is not in the expected encoding.  My code is:

```
try {
    $options = array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
        ); 

    $url="[web-url]/ReceiveNoteService.svc?wsdl";
    $method = "ReceiveNote";
    $error=0;
    $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($client->__getTypes());
echo '</pre>';

$content = array('FileName' => $name, 'DocumentTypeID' => '1', 'Description' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'DocumentBody' => unpack("N*",$contentData));

$noteData = array('AuthenticateUserName' => $userName,
                  'AuthenticatePassword' => $userPass,
                  'FileNumber' => $orderId['closingIntegrationId'],
                  'NoteSubject' => 'Uploaded file name: '.$name,
                  'NoteBody' => 'File '.$name.' added on '.date("Y-m-d h:i A"),
                  'Documents' => $content);

try { 
    $info = $client->$method($noteData);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
    $error = 1;
}

if($error==1) {
    $xml = $fault->faultstring.' ('.$fault->faultcode.')';
}else{
    $xml = $info;
}

echo "results: <br/>";
print_r($xml);
echo '<br/>';
die();
```

The response I am receiving is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => int char
    [1] => duration duration
    [2] => string guid
    [3] => struct ReceiveNoteData {
 int CoordinatorTypeID;
 int CurativeID;
 ReceiveCurativeTypeEnum CurativeType;
 ArrayOfReceiveNoteDocument Documents;
 string FileNumber;
 string NoteBody;
 string NoteSubject;
 int ToCoordinatorID;
}
    [4] => string ReceiveCurativeTypeEnum
    [5] => struct ArrayOfReceiveNoteDocument {
 ReceiveNoteDocument ReceiveNoteDocument;
}
    [6] => struct ReceiveNoteDocument {
 string Description;
 base64Binary DocumentBody;
 int DocumentTypeID;
 string FileName;
 boolean InternalOnly;
}
    [7] => struct ReceiveNoteResponse {
 string Message;
 ReceiveNoteResponseCode ResponseCode;
}
    [8] => string ReceiveNoteResponseCode
    [9] => struct ReceiveNote {
 ReceiveNoteData NoteData;
}
    [10] => struct ReceiveNoteResponse {
 ReceiveNoteResponse ReceiveNoteResult;
}
)

results:
Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'. (HTTP)
```

I am not sure how I change to `application/soap+msbin1`.  I've tried using both soap version 1.1 and 1.2.  I've checked every result I could find on Google and nothing has worked, or even changed the error returned.  I'm tired, and I could use some help.  So any help is appreciated.  haha~

Comment: Soap 1.1 was text/xml.  Soap 1.2 is application/soap+xml.  application/soap+msbin1 is something Microsoft came up with.  The way Microsoft wants you to fix this is by "upgrading" from PHP to .NET.  Resistance is futile.

Comment: hahaha, that's what I thought, but I wasn't sure.  I told the person I'm making this for that we couldn't connect from PHP but I needed to make sure so I've been testing everything I could find.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Are you able make a change on the Microsoft side?  I use PHP's SoapClient to call a Microsoft server and it works so it is possible.  But, in my case, the Microsoft developer did something so his API would speak (accept & return) application/soap+xml.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Woops, forgot to tag you in that last comment.  No, I do not have access, but I am talking with their developers.  Unfortunately, I am not sure they can change it.  They a lot of people already connecting and sending them data through their service.  However, I think I am going to see if they can duplicate what they have as a new service to return a standard content type.  I'll be finding out tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't dug into this too deeply, but I believe the server should respond based on the "Accept" header in the HTTP request.  The other legacy requesters can (and probably do) have "Accept: application/soap+msbin1" and you can have "Accept: application/soap+xml" (if the developers enable it) and .NET will magically comply.  Everybody's happy.